# Calling Stata Functions from R

Tags: r, stata

Is it possible to call Stata functions from R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's now an [RStata package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStata/index.html) that bridges R and Stata.

Comment: This blog post provides a good introduction to RStata https://fsolt.org/blog/2018/08/15/switch-to-r.html

Answer (score 13):

Not directly, i.e. there is no package I am aware of that implements a bridge.

You can always call external programs using `system()` but that is neither elegant nor efficient.  That said, you could prepare data in R, write it out, call Stata and then read the results in; see `help(system)`.

Comment: This is probably the best solution.  Stata has a set of command line tools that allow you to run a .do/.ado file from the shell (windows: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/win/batch.html or unix/linux: http://fmwww.bc.edu/Gstat/docs/stataunixlinux.html#batch)

Comment: There is now an [RStata](https://github.com/lbraglia/RStata) package on GitHub that attempts to create a bridge between R and Stata.

Comment: @Thomas RStata deserves to be it's own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is that Stata doesn't have an interactive interpreter you can pass arguments to.

Dirk is right; you can just go ahead and write the data to a common format 
(if size is large and speed is an issue, fixed width is safe), but you can also just use .dta throughout the process, using read.dta in R and natively reading in Stata.

Also, in R you can call to the system() you can pass a do file or a string containing a bunch of Stata commands.

So, generally, trying to use Stata for this or that task may or may not be worth it, especially if an R equivalent is close by.